# Redirect URL to canonical version cause "too many redirections" error?

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, canonical-link

On my website, both

https://www.datanumen.com/support-doc/access-repair/  (URL1)

and

https://www.datanumen.com/support-doc/access-repair/index.htm (URL2)

will load the URL2 since Apache will search for index.htm under the folder and load it.

Now, to prevent these both URLs will be indexed by Google, I set the canonical URL to URL2 and then add the following redirection in .htaccess, to make sure URL1 will redirect URL2:

```
# 2021-12-15: Redirect help document URL to the canonical version
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteRule ^support-doc/([a-z\-]+)/ /support-doc/$1/index.htm [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But this will cause "Too many redirections" error. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That causes a redirect loop because `/support-doc/something/index.htm` is matched by the regular expression `^support-doc/([a-z\-]+)/` causing `/support-doc/something/index.htm` to redirect to itself.

Perhaps you mean to limit the rewrite rule to the exact URL ending with the trailing slash?   If so the rule should be:

```sh
RewriteRule ^support-doc/([a-z\-]+)/$ /support-doc/$1/index.htm [R=301,L]
```

I added a `$` meaning "ends with" to the rule so that anything after that doesn't match.

---

I would recommend removing `index.htm` from your canonical URL.  In general your canonical URL should be the simplest URL.   `index.htm` is not friendly for users and it should never be shown in a URL.   The index document is there to give the webserver a document that contains the content that should be shown for the directory URL.